# VS Code Intellisense works for Javascript files but not for TypeScript files

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have set up a node.js project where I want to use VS-Code+Typescript.
If I use plain Javascript intellisense is working fine an VS-Code even loads Typescript defintions from the cache *(e.g. ~/.cache/typescript/2.5/node_modules/@types/rethinkdb/index.d.ts)*. But in .ts files this doesn't work at all.

**.js** file (instellisense working)
[image: .js file (instellisense working)]
**.ts** file (intellisense not working)
[image: .ts file (intellisense not working)]

Both files are in the same folder.
My tsconfig.json looks like:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "watch": true
    }
}
```

Am I missing a configuration option or something?

Comment: if you mouseover "rethinkdb", does it give you a file path?  have you tried "triple slashing" it?  
///<reference path="../../../../node_modules/rethinkdb/index.d.ts/>

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Andy's comment gave me a hint, because there was no .d.ts file in the module folder of rethinkdb.
So I copied the .d.ts file from the cache folder to the module folder. I also needed to install the types from [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped):

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node
```

I don't know if this is the recommended way to fix this issue or why VS-Code doesn't resolve the definition files automatically, but at least it works for me now.